# Adding jQuery draggable to Facebook Javascript SDK loaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Myself and a friend are doing a project in college where the user would log into Facebook and they can drag their images in their albums around some drop target templates. We have ran into a problem adding the jQuery draggable to these Javascript generated images.

```
function getAlbumPhotos(access_token, album, count) {
FB.api('/' + album.id + '/photos?limit=' + album.count, function (response) {
  var count = album.count;
  for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    var
    photo = response.data[j],
    parentul = document.getElementById('album_imgs_list'),
    //album_div = document.createElement('div'),
    img = document.createElement('img'),
    childli = document.createElement('li'),
    div = document.createElement('div'),
    photo_id = photo.id;

    img.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + photo_id  + "/picture?access_token="+ access_token;
    img.setAttribute('class', album.id + '_imgs');
    img.setAttribute('class', 'album_imgs');
    img.setAttribute('class', 'dragImgs ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'album_div_img');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'contImgs');

    childli.setAttribute('id', photo_id);

    div.appendChild(img);
    childli.appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById(album.id + 'img').appendChild(childli);
  }
})
```

}

We have tried just adding the class made draggable in custom jQuery code:

```
$(".dragImgs").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    addClass: "true",
    snap: "div[id^=dropTarget]",
    snapMode: "inner",
    appendTo: ".templateContainer",
    opacity: 0.35,
    revert: "invalid" // If set to "invalid", revert will only occur if the draggable has not been dropped on a droppable.
});
```

We have also tried adding the classes ui-draggable and ui-draggable-handle as these classes are  meant to be automatically added to our dragImgs class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a more complete example of how you're retrieving the images from Facebook? How you instantiate the `draggable()` plugin on them depends on the point at which they're added to the DOM.

Comment: I've updated it to show more information. Any help at this point would be appreciated